# Illogical Improper integral with parameter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

$\displaystyle \int_b^c \frac{e^{-ax}*(\sin(bx)-\sin(cx))}{x}\, dx$, $a>0$ and $b,c \in \Bbb R$

I have this improper integral with parameter and I do not understand how to solve it.I have found an answer in my pdf college textbook but the answer is not logical.
Here is what it says:
 $φ(x)= \displaystyle \int_b^c {e^{-ax}*\cos(yx)} \, dy$,  $\;x \in (0,+\infty)$

How did this $\cos(yx)$ term appeared from $\sin bx-\sin cx$?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{-ax}(\sin cx-\sin bx)}x =\int_b^c {e^{-ax}\cos(yx)} \,\mathrm dy. $$

Comment: Bernard What is your proof?

Comment: That still doesn't explain anything!